# Is there a way to quick exit an area to the world map?

Tags: wasteland-2

It takes a very long time to navigate areas like AG Center—is there a way to exit quickly to the world map without navigating all areas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy 'exit area' button. I asked the same thing when I got annoyed having to back track through the prison when trying different tactics.

This is one of the 'old school rpg' elements that I wish the developers ignored!

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to double-click on map near exit, click on globe and go get some tea while your team is running. No easy shortcuts.